# Two events are independent [if] or [if and only if]?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

Two events are independent ...

- **if and only if** $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$  
   
   
   
   
   
   
  ([This I know for sure](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter1/1_4_1_independence.php))

But what about these two, my textbook isn't clear on whether it's [if] or [if and only if]:

- **[if]/[if and only if]** $P(A) = P(A\mid B)$
- **[if]/[if and only if]** $P(B) = P(B\mid A)$

Comment: Definition of independence are 2 second and 1st is conclusion from them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A,B$ (with non-zero probability) are independent iff
$\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)\Pr(B)$ iff $\Pr(A\vert B)=\Pr(A)$ iff $\Pr(B\vert A)=\Pr(B)$.

The proofs in all directions are simple and us the formula $\Pr(A\vert B)\Pr(B)=\Pr(A\cap B)$ in all possible directions.

Comment: The equivalence holds if $P(A) >0$ and $P(B)>0$. In general we can only use $P(A \cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ as the definition of independence.

Comment: Stupid question: But doesn't that mean, that the test $P(A)=P(A|B)$ is enough to conclude that $A,B$ are independent? Suppose $P(A)=P(A|B)$ is true and you thus conclude independence; what if $P(B) \neq P(B|A)$ happened to be true, then you just concluded something false? No?

Comment: @SebastianNielsen It cannot be the case. Either both hold with $=$ or with $\neq$. Think about the interpretation of independence. If I know B happened, it teaches me something about the probability of A. But in that case, if A happened, then I can conclude "the opposite" about B.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy yes, but then $0=0$ and there is no "action".

Answer (score 3):

The events are independent if and only if $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$. This is the definition of independence.

The other conditions, $P(A\mid B)=P(A)$ etc., are not quite equivalent.

With the additional assumption that both events have positive probability, then they would be equivalent since $P(A\mid B)=P(A\cap B)/P(B)$.

However, it is possible that $P(B)=0$, in which case the events are independent since $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$, but $P(A)\neq P(A\mid B)$ since the latter is undefined. So they are really just "if" statements, and to get an "if and only if" you would need to say

> $A$ and $B$ are independent if and only if either $P(B)=0$ or $P(A\mid B)=P(A)$.

Answer (score 2):

Independence definition by $P(A\mid B)=P(A)$ holds asymmetrical information about dependency. Then, as is written, only in case $P(B)>0$ and $P(A\mid B)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$ we obtain $P(A \cap B)=P(A)P(B)$. And because $P(A\mid B)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$ is not defined for $P(B)=0$ we "forget" about initial definition of independence and take as basis $P(A \cap B)=P(A)P(B)$. But this last does not hold the initial asymmetry and becomes symmetrical and from independence for $(A,B)$ we obtain all pairs $(A,B^c),(A^c,B),(A^c,B^c)$ independence.

Let me repeat, that happened loss leaves room for desire improve definition by $P(A\mid B)=P(A)$. Desire define $P(A\mid B)$ as object for which holds $P(A\mid B)P(B)=P(A \cap B)$ gives uncertainty in  $P(B)=0$ case, but I not lost hope one day meet acceptable decision in this case.